# JSON Syntax assistance

Tags: javascript, json, charts

So I'm trying to manipulate some rave charts using JSON. The charts are used in Cognos and it uses visJSON if that helps. I am trying to add a trend line to my bar charts but all the syntax I have found isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
"id":"dataSet",
     "fields":
     [
        {
           "id":"categories",
           "label":"",
           "categories":
           [
              "abc",
              "abc",
              "abc"
           ]
        },
        {
           "id":"series",
           "label":"",
           "categories":
           [
              "abc",
              "abc",
              "abc"
           ]
        },
        {
           "id":"size",
           "label":"abc"
        }
     ],
     "rows":
     [
        [
           0,
           0,
           1500
        ],
        [
           0,
           1,
           1700
        ],
        [
           0,
           2,
           1600
        ],
        [
           1,
           0,
           2400
        ],
        [
           1,
           1,
           2200
        ],
        [
           1,
           2,
           2600
        ],
        [
           2,
           0,
           2800
        ],
        [
           2,
           1,
           1600
        ],
        [
           2,
           2,
           1800
        ]
     ]
  }
 ],
```

Comment: Any code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @GergoErdosi Let me find it, one moment

Comment: This is the 'json' string you're feeding to the charting api?  Or a console log of your json object?  There looks to be missing opening curly braces.

Comment: @aztechy Thank you for this but I only took part of my code from the full thing. In the full thing everything runs fine, I am just trying to get trend lines for the bar charts

Answer (score 0):

A tool that you'd probably find helpful in the future:

http://jsonlint.com/

I ran your JSON through it and it returned this:

```
Parse error on line 1:
"id":"dataSet",    
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

The problem was your extra array bracket at the end.  Here it is corrected:

```
{
    "id": "dataSet",
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": "categories",
            "label": "",
            "categories": [
                "abc",
                "abc",
                "abc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "series",
            "label": "",
            "categories": [
                "abc",
                "abc",
                "abc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "size",
            "label": "abc"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            0,
            0,
            1500
        ],
        [
            0,
            1,
            1700
        ],
        [
            0,
            2,
            1600
        ],
        [
            1,
            0,
            2400
        ],
        [
            1,
            1,
            2200
        ],
        [
            1,
            2,
            2600
        ],
        [
            2,
            0,
            2800
        ],
        [
            2,
            1,
            1600
        ],
        [
            2,
            2,
            1800
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I only took part of my code from the full thing. In the full thing everything runs fine, I am just trying to get trend lines for the bar charts

Comment: Its hard to help without the full code you're trying to use.  Does it return any errors?  If so, what are they?  You may want to tag this with "cognos" as well.

Comment: It runs with no errors. I just need to know how to add the trendlies